# Can't get progressdialog bar to show no matter how I try

Tags: progressdialog

OK, this one is getting frustrating.  I've reviewed the posts here regarding progressdialog bars in AsyncTasks and in regular threads, and nothing is working how I want it to.

In the AsyncTask I've done it this way:

```
@Override
 protected void onPreExecute()
 {
     super.onPreExecute();               
     // initialize the dialog
     progressDialog.setTitle("Please wait...");
     progressDialog.setMessage("Downloading team data...");
     progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
     progressDialog.setCancelable(true);
     progressDialog.show();
 }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... parms) {
    ... stuff

     @Override protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
     progressDialog.dismiss();
  }
```

When I do the above I get nothing until the doInBackground job finishes.  The notes I've read say that using the get() method in the main is blocking the progressbar.

OK.  I have to wait for the task to finish anyway before I can continue, so I wrote the same thing without an AsyncTask:

public class LoadTeamData2 {

```
    Context mContext;
    String teamName = "";
    Boolean result;
    String dataload = "";
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    public LoadTeamData2(Context mContext, String team) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
    teamName = team;
    }

    public Boolean LoadData () {

         ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(mContext);
         progressDialog.setTitle("Please wait...");
         progressDialog.setMessage("Downloading team data...");
         progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
         progressDialog.setCancelable(true);
      //   progressDialog.show();
         ProgressDialog.show(mContext, "Title", "Message", true, true);

            ... more stuff

         progressDialog.dismiss();
             return true;
            }
```

From the above I get the briefest flash of the progressdialog bar.

I've even taken the progressdialog bar out of the called procedures and put the show() and dismiss() methods on both sides of the call to DoStuff.  Still nothing.

At my wit's end here.  Any ideas?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can start the `ProgressDialog` before you start executing the `AsyncTask`, for example:

```
gpsProgress = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Searching...", "Getting...", true, true, new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
    public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {

    }
});

(new SampleAsyncTask(this)).execute(param..);
```

and `onPostExecute(Result)` you may dismiss the dialog.

Please note, that the DialogBox show isn't in `preExecute()`, but in the activity which starts the `AsyncTask`.

Answer (score 0):

The invoke asyncTask.get(XX,XX) blocks the UIThread,

My solution is put the UIlogic in onPostExecute() method, remove asyncTask.get(XX,XX)